# Sending file using CURL in windows

Tags: windows, curl

I'm trying to send a file using curl in windows.

Here's the command i'm using:

```
C:\curl>curl -X POST -F chat_id=@telegramchannel -F photo=@IMAGE.png https://api.telegram.org/bot812312342:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

does anybody know how to solve it and how to use the -F properly with files on windows?

Thanks

Comment: is the IMAGE.png present inside `C:\curl` folder itself?

Comment: @Wander3r yes it's in the c:\curl folder

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. If both the files `telegramchannel` adn `IMAGE.png` are there in the local folder, I am getting a response from telegram server

Comment: @Wander3r the telegramchannel is not a file, it's the telegram channel name. anyway, what curl version are u using, where have u downloaded it from? maybe that's the issue.. or the windows version

Comment: is `@telegramchannel` an actual file?

Answer (score 1):

If `telegramchannel` is not a file, then you have to escape `@` with a backslash or use single quotes to encapsulate the content. As `@` has special meaning in curl context,

either

```
curl -X POST -F chat_id='@telegramchannel' -F photo=@IMAGE.png https://api.telegram.org/bot812312342:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto
```

or

```
curl -X POST -F chat_id=\@telegramchannel -F photo=@IMAGE.png https://api.telegram.org/bot812312342:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto
```

Comment: This one didn't worked but I found the solution, I must use the ID and a number and not the name so I called getUpdates first, got the chat_id from the response and then I used it... tnx a lot for the help

Comment: @user3316244 that still doesn't explain the error you posted in the question. The error says it's looking for a file that does not exist. You modified the curl request according to how it's supposed to be sent to the server and didn't hit this issue anymore.